# Как кастомизировать отрисовку кластеров при отборе jQuery.getJSON, и использовании ".clusterize()"

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Ребята, вопрос такой: есть у меня большая карта с тысячей меток. Гружу из json в objectManager. objectManager я кастомизировал, и он отрисовывает кластера "пироги" с нужной мне палитрой. Тут всё отлично. Но сейчас понадобилось разделить город на полигоны, чтобы при выборе полигона - показывались только метки из этого полигона. Сделал выпадающий список с полигонами, и, при выборе полигона, я делаю так - очистку карты
`myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();`.
jQuery.getJSON отфильтровывает метки через
`var objectsInPolygon=ymaps.geoQuery(json).searchIntersect(myPolygon).`
Заново отрисовываю только нужные мне метки  `myMap.geoObjects.add(objectsInPolygon);`. Но метки не объединены в кластер. Из песочницы брал пример, где есть `myMap.geoObjects.add(objectsInPolygon.clusterize())`  но он делает стандартные кластеры.
Как мне использовать уже созданную модель для кластеров, которую я использую до применения фильтрации? Я пробовал засунуть сюда objectManager, но не получается докрутить. Делал так: `objectManager.add(objectsInPolygon);  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);` - не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Ребята, я разобрался. Дело в том, что `ymaps.geoQuery(json).searchIntersect(myPolygon).` возвращает GeoQueryResult (результат выборки). И просто `objectManager.add` тут не работает.
Вопрос решается, если пробежаться по каждому элементу выборки посредством

> objectsInPolygon.each(function(pm, index) {
> objectManager.add({
> type: 'Feature',
> id: index,
> geometry: {
> type: pm.geometry.getType(),
> coordinates: pm.geometry.getCoordinates()
> },
> properties: pm.properties.getAll(),
> options: pm.options.getAll()
> });
> });